# Error - 'initializing': cannot convert from 'glm::vec2' to 'glm::vec3'

Tags: c++, glm-math

I am making a 3D game engine using C++, following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpAeH0SpR5Y&list=PL6xSOsbVA1eYSZTKBxnoXYboy7wc4yg-Z&index=13).

I am using GLM, and I am getting the error that is in my title. 

I have an array of a custom struct. It saves position, color, and texcoords.

***"Vertex" Struct***

```
struct Vertex {
glm::vec3 position;
glm::vec3 color;
glm::vec2 texcoord;
};
```

***"Vertices" Array:***

```
Vertex vertices[] = {

//POSITION
glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.f),
glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.f),
glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.f),

//COLOR
glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f),
glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.f, 0.f),
glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.f, 1.f),

//TEXCOORDS
glm::vec2(0.f, 1.f),
glm::vec2(0.f, 0.f),
glm::vec2(1.f, 0.f)
};
```

When I click on the error in Visual Studio, it brings me to the end of my Vertice array.

I have googled and searched Stack Overflow, and I cannot find an answer to this problem. I have my full main.cpp file stored [here](https://pastebin.com/prgXQzCi), if that helps anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare the array, thus each array element must be braced in intializer.

```
Vertex vertices[] = {
// First element
{
glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.f),  //POSITION
glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f),  //COLOR
glm::vec2(0.f, 1.f),  // TEXTCOORD
},
// Second element
{
glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.f),
glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f),
glm::vec2(0.f, 0.f),
},
// Third element
{
glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.f),
glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f),
glm::vec2(1.f, 0.f)
}
};
```

Comment: Those braces are optional, reordering the vectors is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing an array of Vertex and trying to initialize it with types glm::vec3 and glm::vec2. The types don't match. What you need to do instead is:

```cpp
Vertex vertices[size];
for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    vertices[i] = Vertex( /* initialize however you need to */ );
}
```

This will initialize and array of size `size` and fill it with `Vertex` objects. Note that this will initialize the array on the stack, which means that you will only be able to store a small amount of vertices. What you should really do is something like:

```cpp
std::vector<Vertex> vertices(size);
for(auto& vertex : vertices) { // range-based for
    vertex = Vertex{ glm::vec3(x,y,z), glm::vec3(x,y,z), glm::vec2(u,v) };
}
```

More info on stack vs heap allocation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/, ranged based for: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-based-loop-c/ and std::vector: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/